# how to get value of h2 element

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

How can I get the content of h2 tag in Prototype framework?

I tried this:

```
alert($$('h2').value());
```

but it haven't done anything.

thx,

Oded

edit: thank you for the fast and great support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$$` returns an Array.

I you only want the first `<h2>`, then access it at index `0`.

```
alert($$('h2')[0].innerHTML);
```

Or you can iterate over the Array using prototypejs' `.each()` method.

```
$$('h2').each(function(el,i) {
    alert(el.innerHTML);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

$$(el) creates an array. You need to iterate over each value, or if you just want the first h2, then use .first()

```
alert($$('h2').first().value());
```

Check out the API http://globalmoxie.com/bm~doc/prototype-160-api.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt you use .html(). jQuery is using this, i think prototype would use something similar.

Try this: alert($('h2').innerHTML);

Comment: Do you know the answer? I don't understand what jQuery has to do with this question.

Comment: I've wanted to point out, that value() is most likely used for input type, not for text / html inside tags - in this case h2.